# What are the ways to create dynamic and interactive reports for end-users?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

A friend of mine claims that in SQL Server there is a way to provide some sort of "interactive" reports for business users. These reports are based on custom tables/columns and end-users have the ability to dynamically select the data they want the report to be based on. I know that it's possible to create reports based on Analysis Services cubes, but he said there should be also another way :) Does anyone know what these 'other' methods are called? Where can I find some resources/training to learn how to do that?

Comment: What do you want to use as the data source? SQL tables and queries, or Analysis Services cubes/data? How interactive do the reports need to be? A user selecting a filter or a user laying out which data items they want presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe he was thinking of [Report Builder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460.aspx)? End users are able to used existing [report models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167048.aspx), [shared datasets, or embedded datasets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239345%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) to build reports.

Answer (score 1):

Power Pivot I bet. Because you said Analysis Services cubes, I think your friend is referring to Power Pivot.